# Openpyxl for cell.value and cell.internal_value error: 'int' object has no attribute 'internal_value'

Tags: python, excel, cell, openpyxl

I am trying to print the value of the cell in excel using `openpyxl`. However, I get the following error: `'int'` object has no attribute `'internal_value'` when I attempt to do `print(cell.internal_value)` and `'int'` object has no attribute `'value'` when I try to do `print(cell.value)`.

I have done the following:

```
for cell in range(2,18):
    print(int(cell.value))
    print(cell.internal_value)
    print(cell.value)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping with range so `cell` is actually an integer **and not** a sheet's cell that is why you are not able to use the above attributes.

You should first try to create a new spreadsheet or load an existing one and then access its cells.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'name_of_your_spreadsheet.xlsx')
# Let's say you want to print the A column
for cell in wb['A2 A18']:
    print(int(cell.value)) #this might not work
    print(cell.internal_value)
    print(cell.value)
```

if you want to use `range` in any case you can do something like this

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'name_of_your_spreadsheet.xlsx')
# Let's say you want to print the A column
for i in range(2,18):
    cell = ws3.cell(column=0, row=i)
    print(int(cell.value)) #this might not work
    print(cell.internal_value)
    print(cell.value)
```